# Добавить с помощью nginx слеш (/) в конце url

Tags: nginx

Подскажите как реализовать переадресацию с URL вида site.ru/controller/action на site.ru/controller/action/ посредством nginx в Yii2.

Comment: И все же - нужно добавить или настроить редирект?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
if ($uri !~ "(\.html|\/)$") {
    return    301    "$uri/";
}
```

В зависимости от задачи вместо $uri можно использовать другие [встроенные переменные](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables).